# How to convert UTF16 Character to UTF8 representation in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsattributedstring

I am trying to draw an attributed string in the UIView and because the char/string is UTF16 I get violet background instead of just the character.  I can change any attributes.

When open characters explorer I see the regular version character and with the violet background.  When I copy paste the character information I get this:

♊︎
Gemini
Unicode: U+264A U+FE0E, UTF-8: E2 99 8A EF B8 8E

This is the drawing code

```
UIFont *signFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:50];
NSAttributedString *signString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"♓" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:248.0/255.0 green:201.0/255.0 blue:12.0/255.0 alpha:0.6],NSFontAttributeName : signFont} ];
NSLog(@"height %f",(signString.size.height));
[signString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake((self.bounds.size.width/2.0) - (signString.size.width/2.0), (self.bounds.size.height/2.0) - (signString.size.height/2.0))];
```

Here is an image of characters with and without violet background.

[image]

Comment: @一二三 I guess that answers why i am getting the violet background character vs not but how do specify in objc to use one or the other?  Thanks!

Comment: Include the appropriate variation selector in the string. It has nothing to do with the string's attributes or Objective-C.

Comment: I think i got it.  Thanks a lot!!  Have a great evening!  I would you something like this as suggested in the other post [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"\u264A",@"\uFE0E"];